# Convert Image to IconData flutter

Tags: flutter

I know there is a way to convert image to `Icon` via `ImageIcon`. But I'm using `FancyBottomNavigation` which is required `TabData` that has parameter `iconData` type `IconData`. Is there anyway to convert image to IconData.

Comment: Your image is png or svg?

Comment: I have both of them

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You can easily use `svg` as IconData using FlutterIcon (Custom Icon Generator). Follow these steps :**

1. Go to [FlutterIcon.com](https://www.fluttericon.com)
2. Drag and drop all your Icons
3. Give a class name (Let's say `CustomIcons`)
4. Download and Unzip.
5. Copy `fonts` folder to your app folder and add the `fonts` as you add a normal font in flutter. ([See here how to add a custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)).
6. Copy custom class `CustomIcons` that we generated to your `lib` directory.
7. `Use CustomIcons` as `IconData` :

   `Icon(CustomIcons.hamburger)`

Comment: If you don't understand you can use this source someone very good explained  
https://medium.com/deviniti-technology-driven-blog/the-best-way-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-project-6381ab697813