# how to import a svg icon to icondata

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter and using a plugin called FloatBoxPanel, for the property `panelIcon` a IconData is expected, I created a svg icon, now i dont know how to use it. directly usage will display error:

```
The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'. (Documentation)
The argument type 'SvgPicture' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'. (Documentation)
```

Here is part of this code, plz let me know if it is possible, thank you!!

```dart
// panelIcon's Type:IconData
panelIcon: Icon(
  SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/candle.svg',
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
    allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
  ),
),
```

Comment: You'll probably have more than one custom icon. I would recommend generating a Custom Icon Font. Have a look here: https://www.fluttericon.com/ Then, it'll be as easy as `panelIcon: Icon(CustomIcons.candle, size: 20),`.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65841239/11992780)

Answer (score 3):

There is a good way to create an IconData from SVG images, by converting it to a .ttf file format, then adding it to pubspec.yaml as a font family...

Please check the following for the entire process: (**Recomended**)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-application/

P.S. read it from "How to Generate Custom Icons in Flutter" section.

**IF THE LINK DOESN'T WORK!** start reading here

How to Generate Custom Icons in Flutter
We will be able to generate custom icons through https://www.fluttericon.com/  It allows us to either:

• Upload a SVG that gets converted into an icon
• Choose from a huge selection of icons from a different set of icon packages

There is a package called FlutterIcon https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon  that has all of the icons shown, but due to it’s heavy size, I recommended only choosing the icons that you need and not using it.

Let’s demonstrate how to import custom icons into your application using this website.

On FlutterIcon.com:

• Choose the icons that you want to use/upload a SVG file
• Give a meaningful name to your icon class (We’ll call our class CustomIcons)
• Press Download

In the .zip folder that you downloaded, there are several files:

A fonts folder with a TTF file with the name of the class you chose
A config.json file that's used to remember what icons you chose
A dart class with the name of the class you chose

Inside your project, import the .ttf file into a folder called fonts under the assets directory.

Place the .dart class inside your lib folder. If you take a look inside the dart file, you will see something similar (you might see more IconData objects if you chose more than one icon to download):

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomIcons {
  CustomIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'CustomIcons';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData pill = IconData(0xea60, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

Add the following to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
fonts:
      - family: CustomIcons
        fonts:
          - asset: fonts/CustomIcons.ttf
```

Run "flutter pub get" in the terminal or click Pub get inside the IDE.

Go to the place where you want to use your custom icons and use it like this:

```
n.dart
TextFormField(
  controller: pillNameTextEditingController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'What is the pill\'s name?',
      prefixIcon: Icon(CustomIcons.pill)
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter a pill name';
    }
    return null;
  }
)
```

**Troubleshooting Custom Icons in Flutter**
If your custom icons are showing up as squares with X’s in them, something is not right. You might also see in the logger the following warnings:

Warning: No fonts specified for font CustomIcons
Warning: Missing family name for font.

This could be for several reasons:

• Make sure your pubspec.yaml file is valid. Meaning there are no extra spaces, indention, and so on. You can use this tool for it.
• Make sure that you have correctly referenced your font in your pubspec.yaml file.
• Make sure that you have placed your .ttf file inside a fonts directory under the root directory of your project (not inside the assets directory).
• Uninstall your application and reinstall it on your device.

Comment: The links can break in future. Please copy the relevant code/steps into your answer.

Comment: Thanks @happy-san, I've just added the content.

Answer (score 1):

The type `IconData` has to have an `Icon()`. You cannot set it to an Image or Svg.

You have 2 solutions. Either use what @Thierry said by converting the Svg to an `Icon` or change the code in the package to support an `Image` instead of an `Icon`.

Answer (score -5):

Svg in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

1.add package in pubspec.yaml

2.dependencies: flutter_svg: any

3.assets:
-assets/images/

4.to insert svg.

SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/your_image.svg', width: 24, height: 29.2),