# Flutter - Slidable, cannot put svg for icon property of Slidable

Tags: flutter

```
Slidable(
      groupTag: 0,
      key: UniqueKey(),
      endActionPane: ActionPane(
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
                //whatever I will do here
            },
            icon: Icons.delete
          )// SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.trash.svg()),)
        ],
      ),
      child: _makeColumnTile(
        myCard,
      ),

    );
```

This is just a basic slidable item, which I am doing for every list item I have. I understand, and can work with slidable and listTile. However, I want to put my own custom svg file I saved in my assets folder, not pre-built Icons. But the `icon:` is apparently only wanting `IconData`

I tried putting svg directly with `SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.trash.svg())`, but the error is

> The argument type `SvgPicture` can't be assigned to the parameter type `IconData?`,

also when I want to assign `Icon` to `icon`, this error pops up.

> The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?.

I understand why I cannot assign those properties, but isn't there any way I could solve this problem?

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65841239/11992780)

Comment: Hmm, so the only way is to make IconData manually. I guessed there should be an approach similar to this, but not allowing svg or image for icon property seems silly, and I think devs should fix that, shouldn't they? Regardless, If this is the only way, I will have to use this; thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SlidableAction` only accepts `IconData` in its `icon` property. A list of MaterialIcons is available [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html).

```dart
SlidableAction(
   icon: Icons.archive,
 ),
```

For your use case, you can instead use a `CustomSlidableAction` (check the package's API reference [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_slidable/latest/flutter_slidable/CustomSlidableAction-class.html)).

```dart
CustomSlidableAction (
  child: //Your action's icon or label.
 )
```

You can pass your SVG as a child to it.

Comment: God damn, mate, you telling me all I had to do was to use CustomSlidableAction instead of that stupid SlidableAction. Thank you so much. Everything is working as intended now.

Comment: Ahha its always the simplest of solutions sometimes 

Answer (score 0):

Flutter can't generate IconData from svgs. You must convert it to a ttf file and use it as your icon source.
You can use an online converter like https://fluttericon.com or do it locally with a package like https://pub.dev/packages/icon_font_generator

Then import it as following in your pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
fonts:
- family: MyIcons
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/MyIcons.ttf
```

Then pass the Icon to your widget:

```
 SlidableAction(
      onPressed: (_) {},
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      icon: MyIcons.Delete,
      label: 'Delete',
    ),
```